# How to configure multiple domain on single Google Analytics account

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, gtag.js

I'm upgrading old google analytics code (ga) to latest gtag implementations.

in the old implementation we were using couple of site under one account using below command,

```
ga('create', '<TrackingID>', '<DomainName>');
```

but in the new implementation we are required to use

```
gtag('config', '<TrackingID>');
```

I managed to get google tracking working using the provided code by google, but I had to create two properties with different urls,

[image: Site - 1]

[image: Site - 2]

Is there a way to record analytics from both sites under same property.

Also in the old implementation we were able to push javascript function as below,

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', '<TrackingID>', '<Domain>']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(function () {
    foo(1000);
});
```

Is there a way to push function using "gtag"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With gtag.js you can use following code:

```
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {
  'linker': {
    'domains': ['example.com']
  }
});
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cross-domain

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for this scenario is to configure cross domain tracking in GA. Please follow this video for more details - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cb7oY4B9qX4